# Removing related data from the corresponding table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables with some data as shown in the screen shot[image]

Please have a look at them. There is a table tbCompanyAgent which contains some information from tbLicence also. After performing complex business operations we are able to detect LicenceTypeId field in tbLicence from LicenceTypeNames feild in tbCompanyAgent(Where LicenceTypes is saved as comma separated string). Then after detecting Id, we save it in LicenceTypeId field in tbCompanyAgent.

If we have to update table tbLicence, we first remove records from the table on  basis of LicenceType field which is behaving as Group Id, then we reinsert in the table with newer values for other columns in the table tbLicence. We have to do like it because of complex business requirement.

Now my question is if we have to update tbLicence, Let us suppose that we have now LicenceTypesName column with new values like "Life, Accident and Health". Then all the corresponding enteries should be removed from tbCompanyAgent.

I want to do something like below lines of code... 
It will first check where there is any changes in LicenceTypesNames field or bis blank (the case for the first time insertion) then perform insertion and delete operation. Otherwise it should perform simply insertion operation only.

```
          Declare @LTN as nvarchar(MAX);

          SELECT @LTN = LicenceTypesNames 
          FROM tbLicence 
          WHERE LicenceType = @LicenceType

         IF @LTN != @LicenceTypesNames
         DELETE FROM tbCompanyAgent  
         WHERE LicenceNumber IN (SELECT DISTINCT LicenceNumber 
         FROM tbLicence 
         WHERE LicenceType = @LicenceType)  
         INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbLicence]( ...) 
         ELSE 
         INSERT INTO  [dbo].[tbLicence](...)
```

Can anyone provide me better query method!!! Please help

Comment: research MERGE statement

Comment: As @Pieter suggested you can use Merger statement. Below is a link which explains the use of MERGE statement:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Can anyone provide code snippet in the above context...